# decltype(auto) vs auto&& to perform generic handling of function's return type

Tags: c++, c++14

When using `auto&&` to handle a function returning an lvalue:

```
int func()
{
   int v=42;
   return v;
}

auto && v = func();
```

What are the consequences of treating `v` as a reference instead of an lvalue? Do these consequences justify the use of `decltype(auto)` instead of `auto&&` to perform generic handling of function's return type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`auto&&` is already optimal for capturing function return values, such that the differences of `decltype(auto)` can only be disadvantages. In your example, *lifetime extension* is applied to the otherwise-temporary object returned from the function. This causes it to behave essentially the same as a directly named object, with the effect that the reference qualifier gets "erased."

Using `decltype(auto)` with a return-by-value function causes its return value object to be moved into the local. Depending what's inside the function, copy elision may apply which removes the distinction between the local and the temporary. But that only applied sometimes, whereas reference-bound lifetime extension is unconditional.

Even when applied, copy elision doesn't remove the requirement that the return object *could* be copied or moved. `decltype(auto)` can't initialize an object of non-movable type from a function return whereas `auto &&` can, modulo the distinction between a local and a temporary with the lifetime of a local.

As it happens, that distinction can only be made by `decltype`, and it can only be made outside the local scope by `decltype(auto)`. Since you usually *want* to treat lifetime-extended objects as locals, it is best to mind parentheses and `std::decay`s when using `decltype`, and not to use `decltype(auto)` for function parameters (which is the most common application of `auto &&`).

Comment: There is at least one exception, when `decltype(auto)` is necessary: when testing both correctness of returned type of some function and returned value, then `decltype(auto)` is unavoidable. [Example](https://github.com/tomilov/variant/blob/72a671d2e56d189b3fe9289956b851fe7645af08/test/include/test/visit.hpp#L254).