# Why decltype is used in trailing return types?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype, return-type-deduction

consider the following codes:

```
template< class T1 , class T2>
auto calc( T1 a , T2 b )
{
   return a + b ;
}


template< class T1 , class T2>
auto calc( T1 a , T2 b ) -> decltype( a + b )
{
   return a + b ;
}
```

Whats the difference in the second code ?
Can you give some example where this makes a difference or does it make a difference here ?

Answer (score 7):

Note that the plain `auto` return type is something that is only for C++14, whereas the trailing return type with `decltype` is for C++11. The difference comes when references enter the picture, e.g. in code like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Test
{
    int& data;

    auto calc1()
    {
       return data;
    }

    auto calc2() -> decltype(data)
    {
       return data;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int x;
    Test t{x};
    static_assert(std::is_same<int, decltype(t.calc1())>::value, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<int&, decltype(t.calc2())>::value, "");
}
```

If you want to remove `->decltype()` and keep your code behaving the same, you can use the C++14 construct `decltype(auto)`

```
decltype(auto) calc3() // same as calc2() above
{
    return data;
}
```

which preserves the referenceness of the return type as well.

If you already know that your return type is a reference, just make it explicit

```
auto& calc4() // same as calc2() above
{
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Rex :)
Ok so apart from reference preserving both are same. So which one should one use or which one is safer to use ?

Comment: it depends on what you want. I would use `auto` and `auto&` to make it explicit what the referenceness of the return type is. Sometimes `decltype` can have its advantages, e.g. in SFINAE contexts where you want to delay  instantiation etc. [But that's advanced stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24109800/819272).

Comment: decltype(auto) can sometimes be dangerous. For example:
decltype(auto) foo () { auto x = 5; return (x); }
Because (x) is an expression, is type is int& (many people surround return this parentheses). So this function returns a reference to a local, which is a bug!

Comment: @MinasMina yes, that's right, once should only do that for `operator[]` type of class members that return `*this;` , and never for function local variables