# How to verify if returned `auto` variable is a reference

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, auto

While doing code maintenance I found code like this:

```
auto networkEntry = _networkEntries[key];
networkEntry.port = port;
networkEntry.scope = scope;
```

The map data type used for `_networkEntries` has two overloaded versions of the `operator[]`:

```
template<class T>
class Map {
    // ... simplified STD compatible container ...
    T & Map::operator[](const Key & key);
    const T Map::operator[](const Key & key) const;
};
```

The data type used in the map is a simple `struct`.

Now I just wondered, the returned value for `auto` could be a copy of the data structure, or a reference to the data structure. If a copy is returned, the assignments would not affect the stored values in the map.

I have three related question for this case:

- **Can I know or test which version of the `operator[]` was used?**
- **Which C++ rules do apply here?**
- **Is there a way, *using `auto`*, to make sure the reference is used?**

Comment: Does the funtion really return a `const T`? Or is it `const T&`?

Answer (score 7):

```
auto networkEntry = _networkEntries[key];
```

Here `networkEntry` will never be a reference type, as [`auto` type deduction rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) follow [*template argument* deduction rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

In short, you need to either say:

- `auto& x = y;`

  - Will compile only if `y` can be bound to an *lvalue reference*.
- `auto&& x = y;`

  - Will always deduce a reference type, either *lvalue*/*rvalue* *reference* depending on the value category of `y`.
- `decltype(auto) x = y;`

  - Will deduce exactly the type of `y` - it **can** deduce a reference or a value type. See [What are some uses of decltype(auto)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737/what-are-some-uses-of-decltypeauto).
  - As Yakk said, if `y` is not a reference type, `x` becomes an *rvalue reference* bound to the non-reference temporary `y`.

In order to deduce a reference.

Comment: Posh answer, +1, you might want to wack something about `const` in though.

Comment: You should be clear with `auto&&` that if `y` is "not a reference type" (ok, a prvalue, but anyone asking this question doesn't know what a prvalue is), `x` becomes an rvalue reference bound to the non-reference temporary `y`.

Comment: Good answer. Since you were hitting all the bases, might as well mention 'const auto &'

Answer (score 3):

1. If the implied `this` pointer at the calling site is `const`, then the `const` version of `operator[]` will be called, else the non-`const` version is called. So if the function containing your code is `const`, and `_networkEntries` is a member variable of that class, then the `const` version will be called.
2. As above.
3. If you want a reference, then use `auto&` **not** `auto` for the type at the calling site: `auto& networkEntry = _networkEntries[key];`.