# Are there any realistic use cases for `decltype(auto)` variables?

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, type-deduction, decltype-auto

Both from my personal experience and from consulting answers to questions like [What are some uses of decltype(auto)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737/what-are-some-uses-of-decltypeauto) I can find plenty of valuable use cases for `decltype(auto)` as a *function return type placeholder*.

However, I am seriously struggling to think of any valid (i.e. useful, realistic, valuable) use case for `decltype(auto)` variables. The only possibility that comes to mind is to store the result of a function returning `decltype(auto)` for later propagation, but `auto&&` could be used there as well and it would be simpler.

I've even searched throughout all my projects and experiments, and the 391 occurrences of `decltype(auto)` are all return type placeholders.

So, **are there any realistic use cases for `decltype(auto)` variables?** Or it this feature only useful when used as a return type placeholder?

---

> How do you define "realistic"?

I am looking for a use case that provides value *(i.e. it's not just an example to show how the feature works)* where `decltype(auto)` is the perfect choice, compared to alternatives such as `auto&&` or to not declaring a variable at all.

The problem domain doesn't matter, it could be some obscure metaprogramming corner case or arcane functional programming construct. However, the example would need to make me go *"Hey, that's clever/beautiful!"* and using any other feature to achieve the same effect would require more boilerplate or have some sort of drawback.

Comment: How do you define "realistic"?

Comment: @NicolBolas: I am looking for some use case that provides value (i.e. it's not just an example to show how the feature works) where `decltype(auto)` is the perfect choice, compared to alternatives such as `auto&&` or not declaring a variable at all. The domain doesn't matter, it could be some obscure metaprogramming corner case. But the example would need to make me go *"Hey, that's clever!"* and using any other feature to achieve the same effect would require more boilerplate or have some sort of drawback. Sorry that I cannot be more precise.

Comment: @Eljay: I'm flattered! I can give you plenty of examples for `decltype(auto)`-returning functions... but variables baffle me at the moment :)

Comment: I recently made use of `decltype(auto)` variables for NRVO like this: https://godbolt.org/z/9oz37Was1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not a very deep answer, but basically `decltype(auto)` [was proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html) to be used for return type deduction, to be able to deduce references when the return type is actually a reference (contrary to plain `auto` that will never deduce the reference, or `auto&&` that will always do it).

The fact that it can also be used for variable declaration not necessarily means that there should be *better-than-other* scenarios. Indeed, using `decltype(auto)` in variable declaration will just complicate the code reading, given that, for a variable declaration, is has exactly the same meaning. On the other hand, the `auto&&` form allows you to declare a constant variable, while `decltype(auto)` doesn't.

Comment: I don’t see how auto&& allows you to declare a constant variable (references are never const at the top level) whereas decltype(auto) allows you to do that without any problem.

Comment: @L.F. sorry for the late respond, probably I expressed incompletetly: I meant that there are certain cases where you can convert to constant by adding the `const` modifier in `auto&&`, whereas `decltype(auto)` doesn't allow you to do so. I know it is not possible to use in all the scenarios (as in `int a; int& b=a; const auto&& c=b;`), but it is in cases like `int foo() { return 0; } const auto&& a=foo();`. Probably not very useful but possible. Anyway, please correct me if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 18):

Essentially, the case for variables is the same for functions.  The idea is that we store the result of an function invocation with a `decltype(auto)` variable:

```
decltype(auto) result = /* function invocation */;
```

Then, `result` is

- a non-reference type if the result is a prvalue,
- a (possibly cv-qualified) lvalue reference type if the result is a lvalue, or
- an rvalue reference type if the result is an xvalue.

Now we need a new version of `forward` to differentiate between the prvalue case and the xvalue case: (the name `forward` is avoided to prevent ADL problems)

```
template <typename T>
T my_forward(std::remove_reference_t<T>& arg)
{
    return std::forward<T>(arg);
}
```

And then use

```
my_forward<decltype(result)>(result)
```

Unlike `std::forward`, this function is used to forward `decltype(auto)` variables.  Therefore, it does not unconditionally return a reference type, and it is supposed to be called with `decltype(variable)`, which can be `T`, `T&`, or `T&&`, so that it can differentiate between lvalues, xvalues, and prvalues.  Thus, if `result` is

- a non-reference type, then the second overload is called with a non-reference `T`, and a non-reference type is returned, resulting in a prvalue;
- an lvalue reference type, then the first overload is called with a `T&`, and `T&` is returned, resulting in an lvalue;
- an rvalue reference type, then the second overload is called with a `T&&`, and `T&&` is returned, resulting in an xvalue.

Here's an example.  Consider that you want to wrap `std::invoke` and print something to the log: (the example is for illustration only)

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) my_invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    decltype(auto) result = std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    my_log("invoke", result); // for illustration only
    return my_forward<decltype(result)>(result);
}
```

Now, if the invocation expression is

- a prvalue, then `result` is a non-reference type, and the function returns a non-reference type;
- a non-const lvalue, then `result` is a non-const lvalue reference, and the function returns a non-const lvalue reference type;
- a const lvalue, then `result` is a const lvalue reference, and the function returns a const lvalue reference type;
- an xvalue, then `result` is an rvalue reference type, and the function returns an rvalue reference type.

Given the following functions:

```
int f();
int& g();
const int& h();
int&& i();
```

the following assertions hold:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(my_invoke(f)), int>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(my_invoke(g)), int&>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(my_invoke(h)), const int&>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(my_invoke(i)), int&&>);
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GojxyLZDePXN2wZG), [move only test case](https://wandbox.org/permlink/K0KDeFT8B72dCRLt))

If `auto&&` is used instead, the code will have some trouble differentiating between prvalues and xvalues.

Comment: I think this is a step in the right direction, but your example causes an unnecessary copy when `f` returns a *prvalue*, and inhibits *mandatory copy elision*. Take a look at my version here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/awuVxy

Comment: Posted a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444893/correctly-propagating-a-decltypeauto-variable-from-a-function - I am not convinced that `decltype(auto)` is the best solution to this problem. The `on_scope_success` solution seems cleaner.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: "*I am not convinced that decltype(auto) is the best solution to this problem.*" And that's what makes your question opinion-based: who decides what "best" is? LF's code is extremely readable, while your alternative example is... weird. It's not clear why it is you're doing what you're doing or what the purpose of it is. It's a lot of additional code just to *maybe* avoid a copy/move (since pretty much every compiler will NVRO that code).

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Indeed, your own definition of "realistic" specifically states "*using any other feature to achieve the same effect would require more boilerplate*". Well, your alternative definitely requires more boilerplate. So by your own definition, this is a "realistic" example.

Comment: @NicolBolas: it's not about NRVO, the version presented by this answer introduces an extra *copy*! See https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/awuVxy. I don't see that as a minor drawback, I see that as a major flaw. As an example, it prevents usage of move-only objects. So no, it doesn't achieve the "same effect" as my version. If the extra copy doesn't matter we might as well use `auto` or `auto&&` instead of `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo You are right, my previous answer is completely wrong.  I have updated my answer with a better version (not resorting to `if constexpr`).  I also added a move only type test case.

Comment: @L.F.: this still seems to be wrong. Any *prvalue* gets copied, like before. And RVO is not possible. See https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/gNCk_x

Comment: @Vittorio I am soooo stupid.  Now it should be right.

Comment: @L.F.: now it moves instead of copying, but prevents RVO as far as I can see.