# Return different types with different template parameter value (but same type)

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, return-type

What I want to do is to define 3 functions like these:

```cpp
template<int t = 0> int test() { return 8; }
template<int t = 1> float test() { return 8.8; }
template<int t = 2> std::string test() { return "8.9"; }

int main()
{
    int a = test<0>();
    float b = test<1>();
    std::string c = test<2>();
    return 0;
}
```

They use the same type of template parameter but return different types.

I believe there must be some way to do that (like  `std::get<>()` does it), but I can not find how to do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks to me like you are after function template specialization. Needing to provide a different implementation for each of the calls fits the bill. There is however one caveat, and it's that a specialization may not alter the signature of the primary template being specialized, only the implementation. This means we cannot do e.g.

```
template<int t> int test(); // Primary
template<> int test<0>() { return 8; } // OK, signature matches
template<> float test<1>() { return 8.8; } // ERROR
```

But we are not toasted yet. The signature of the specialization has to match the one that primary will get for a specific argument. So if we make the return type *dependent* on the template parameter, and resolve to the correct type, we could define our specialization just fine.

```
template<int t> auto test() -> /* Magic involving t that resolves to int, float, string */;
template<> int test<0>() { return 8; }
template<> float test<1>() { return 8.8; }
template<> std::string test<2>() { return "8.9"; }
```

Does something like that exist? Yes, and you hinted at it. We can use `std::tuple`. It has a [`std::tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) utility that can map an integer to one of a type sequence (the tuple's elements). With a little helper, we can construct our code to work the way you wish:

```
using types = std::tuple<int, float, std::string>;

template<int t> auto test() -> std::tuple_element_t<t, types>;

template<> int test<0>() { return 8; }
template<> float test<1>() { return 8.8; }
template<> std::string test<2>() { return "8.9"; }
```

Now every specialization matches the signature the primary would end up with. And so we get an approval from our compiler.

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/21edf9a7c79d3e39)

Answer (score 8):

The *[@StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller)* and *[@formerlyknownas_463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459323/return-different-type-with-different-template-parameter-value-but-same-type-in/57459534#57459534)* have provided a well-explained template specialization way of doing it. Alternatively, one can combine the three functions to one single function using *[if-constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)* and with a [`decltype(auto)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737/what-are-some-uses-of-decltypeauto) return in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std::literals;

template<int t>
constexpr decltype(auto) test() noexcept
{
    if constexpr (t == 0) return 8;
    else if constexpr (t == 1) return 8.8f;
    else if constexpr (t == 2) return "8.9"s;
}
```

**([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xWVhtWAVNJnc98lo))**

Answer (score 4):

You declared the same template 3 times, while you actually want specialisations. As far as I know you cannot specialize on return type directly (*). However, there is nothing that cannot be solved with an additional layer of indirection. You can do something along the line of:

```
#include <string>

template <int> struct return_type_tag {};
template <> struct return_type_tag<0> { using type = int; };
template <> struct return_type_tag<1> { using type = float; };
template <> struct return_type_tag<2> { using type = std::string; };

template <int x> typename return_type_tag<x>::type test();

template<> int test<0>() { return 8; }
template<> float test<1>() { return 8.8; }
template<> std::string test<2>() { return "8.9"; }

int main()
{
    int a = test<0>();
    float b = test<1>();
    std::string c = test<2>();

    return 0;
}
```

(*) actually you can, with a small trick, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57459547/4117728). The only benefit of my approach is that it already worked pre-c++11.