# How to use result_of with function typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Let's say I have something, following the example on cppreference.com, but specified differently:

```
typedef double call_t(char, int&);
```

I need such a form of invocation of `result_of` that would give back the return type of the function signature defined as the above `call_t`. That is something that I could use as:

```
template <class Signature>
std::result_of<SOME_MAGIC_AROUND(Signature)>::type call(Signature* f)
{
    return (*f)();
}

double d = call(fn); // where `fn` is declared as having `call_t` type
```

Doing `result_of<call_t>::type` doesn't work. I've tried also various combinations around it, but came to nothing.

Comment: If you can use c++14, you could just use [`decltype(auto)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737/what-are-some-uses-of-decltypeauto).

Comment: If I only could use any newer standard than C++03, I'd solve lots of other problems :D

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the parameters too. e.g.

```
template <class Signature>
typename std::result_of<Signature*(char, int&)>::type call(Signature* f)
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    return (*f)(...);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5UWu3POxUzzm07Qs)

---

[`std::result_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) has been deprecated since C++17, you can use `std::invoke_result` instead.

```
template <class Signature>
typename std::invoke_result<Signature*, char, int&>::type call(Signature* f)
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    return (*f)(...);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

> `Signature` is a template parameter, but expected to be a typedef for a function. I need its "return type" so that I can use as a return type for the call forwarder - regardless of what parameters a user might have specified for `Signature`.

You can make a type trait which gets the return type from the function type. e.g.

```
template <typename F>
struct return_type_of_function {};
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type_of_function<R(Args...)> {
    using type = R;
};
```

then use it as

```
template <class Signature>
typename return_type_of_function<Signature>::type call(Signature* f)
{
    return (*f)(...);
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7ofefVF4qtveU3AV)

Comment: Ok, the problem I haven't mentioned though is that this should be a universal callback wrapper (the code is shared between C++03 code and C++11 code, hence and extra feature for the latter).

`Signature` is a template parameter, but expected to be a typedef for a function. I need its "return type" so that I can use as a return type for the call forwarder - regardless of what parameters a user might have specified for `Signature`.

Comment: @Ethouris Answer revised.

Comment: So... I've hit this code again after I lost it due to its uselessness and no solution, and yes, I ended up making my own "return type extractor", it was much easier than finding anything in the standard. Pity.