# Perfect forward return type but with const

Tags: c++

I want to perfect-forward a call to a function, but I always want to return a `const` version of the returned type. I mean, when returning a reference, I want a `const&` instead. How can I achieve that?

- I don't care about non-reference types. After all, returning a const T (without a reference) is not much different than `T`.
- I care only about a `const` at the top level. If `T` is a pointer type, or some other more complex type, I do not want to add constness somewhere deeper.

If I just forward the call normally:

```
template<class Func, class... Args>
decltype(auto) Example(Func f, Args&&... args) 
{ 
    return fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
}
```

and `f` happens to return, say, `int&` then I just get just that: `int&`. But I would like to get a `const int&` instead.

`decltype(auto) const`, or `decltype(auto const)` seem to be illegal.

Comment: Blueprint: use decltype with declval to figure out what `f` returns. Use a simple helper class to munge the return type. The End.

Comment: For your attempted solutions, be aware that if `auto` were to resolve to `int&` then adding `const` to `auto` would give `int & const`, not `const int &`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I will definetely try that! However, after reading answers like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24109800, I find replacing `decltype(auto)` with `decltype(expr)` very volatile in my mind (what if there is a corner-case I didn't know?)

Comment: What's the point in returning a `const` value, really? I mean, I get that it'll prevent accidental assignments to a temporary (like is already the case for built-ins), but is that worth all this? Is there some _actual_ practical problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings const for a temporary? Not really useful. But returning `const T&` instead of `T&` is significant.

Comment: I am also confused about the goal here? The description is not quite clear. You say you want to turn a value const, which would be `int` -> `int const`. But returning const values doesn't make any sense in c++. But the the example you give is `int&` -> `int const&`. Which is *not* adding const to the return type. That would be `int&` -> `int& const`. So you get a reference and want to turn into a const reference?

Comment: @Chronial I see how by saying "const value" I confused you. I reworded the quesiton, I hope my intent is now clearer.

Comment: Yes, that's better. But it's still missing a bit: What should happen when fun() returns `int`? I assume Example() should also return `int`? What about `int*` and `int**`?

Comment: I see, this is a totally different thing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. References are transformed to `const&`. Any other type remains unchanged. However, I would like to hear a second opinion, if there are some corner cases I didn't consider.

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct add_const_to_ref {
        using type = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct add_const_to_ref<T&> {
        using type = const T&;
};

template<typename T>
using add_const_to_ref_t = typename add_const_to_ref<T>::type;

template<class Func, class... Args>
add_const_to_ref_t<decltype(std::declval<Func>()(std::forward<Args>(std::declval<Args&&>())...))> ConstInvoke(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
            return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

The following test:

```
#include <iostream>

int& foo(int& x) {
        return x;
}

int bar() {
        return 5;
}
int main() {
        int x = 0;
        std::cout << std::is_same_v<int&, decltype(ConstInvoke(foo, x))> << "\n";
        std::cout << std::is_same_v<int, decltype(ConstInvoke(foo, x))> << "\n";
        std::cout << std::is_same_v<const int&, decltype(ConstInvoke(foo, x))> << "\n";

        std::cout << std::is_same_v<int&, decltype(ConstInvoke(bar))> << "\n";
        std::cout << std::is_same_v<int, decltype(ConstInvoke(bar))> << "\n";
        std::cout << std::is_same_v<const int&, decltype(ConstInvoke(bar))> << "\n";
};
```

Gives the expected result:

0
0
1
0
1
0

i.e.

`ConstInvoke(foo, x)` returns `const int&`,

`ConstInvoke(bar)` returns `int`

---

An alternative, to simplify the horrible `ConstInvoke`, one can try like this:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) as_const_to_ref(T&& arg) {
        return (add_const_to_ref_t<T>)(std::forward<T>(arg));
}

template<class Func, class... Args>
decltype(auto) ConstInvoke2(Func f, Args&&... args)
{
            return as_const_to_ref(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: You can replace `decltype(std::declval<Func>()(std::forward<Args>(std::declval<Args&&>())...))` with `std::invoke_result<Func, Args...>` to make this a bit more readable.