# Deducing constness of a pair member in a template return type

Tags: c++, return-type-deduction

Assume I have an iterator referencing a `std::pair`. It might point into a map, so first_type would be `const`. But it might also be a vector of pairs, and first_type is mutable. How do I define a function that returns a reference to the first of that pair?

What I have tried is this:

```cpp
template<typename TPairIter>
typename std::iterator_traits<TPairIter>::value_type::first_type& first_of_pair_func(TPairIter it) 
{return it->first;}
```

However, this gives errors for my code when `first_type` is `const`. Apparently, `std::iterator_traits<TPairIter>::value_type::first_type` strips the `const`.

*Note:* Other code needs to deduce the return type from this function by doing `decltype(first_of_pair_func(it))`.

Comment: Err, this seems to work as is? https://godbolt.org/z/bcT74x The `decltype(auto)` version is definitely clearer, but I'd be concerned if this version is failing.

Comment: @HTNW: I am entirely unsure about this. I got errors with this version which disappeared when I used `decltype(auto)`. However, I have since moved on (finally!) and am too weary of this to investigate further. (I know this might bite me later. BTDT. But it's 5:40am on Monday before Xmas, I have been on vacation for almost two weeks, I am only pursuing this because I couldn't sleep, and I am running out of steam here.)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, after having battled this since 24hrs ago, I figured out the solution within 5 minutes after posting the question here. `:-/`

This does the trick:

```cpp
template<typename TPairIter>
auto first_of_pair_func(TPairIter it) -> decltype(auto) {return (it->first);}
```

Note [the parentheses around the returned expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24109944/140719). Without them, the return type is the type of the data member `first` in `std::pair`, which has no reference qualification. With them, the return type has a `&` since `it->first` is an lvalue.

Comment: @HNTW: Please do not change the code I wrote which solved the problem. First of all, formatting is entirely subjective and should not be changed. Second, the trailing return type does indeed make a syntactic difference which might matter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24109800/140719. Given that this code uses a lot of template functions calling each other, some of them recursively, I deliberately choose the trailing return type even though the all the code we _currently_ have compiles even without. Thanks.

Comment: That post says nothing about trailing vs. leading `decltype(auto)` (it's about `decltype(return-expr)` vs `decltype(auto)`, with the former necessitating the trailing return type and the latter just replicating it), and [reproducing the example](https://godbolt.org/z/Pxfsd8) given with a leading `decltype(auto)` works just as well as the original trailing `decltype(auto)`. I'm fairly certain that trailing vs leading `decltype(auto)` makes no difference in *any* case. What kind of difference would you even expect? The "return type delay" comes from `decltype(auto)` itself, not its location.