# Why is the C++20 concept not compatible with "const auto&"?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, type-deduction

```
template<typename T>
concept Octet = 1 == sizeof(T);

// ok
Octet decltype(auto) c = 'a';

// ok
void f1(const auto&) {}

// ok
void f2(Octet auto) {}

// ok
void f3(Octet auto&&) {}

// error: expected ‘auto’ or ‘decltype(auto)’ after ‘Octet’
void f4(Octet const auto&) {}

// error: cannot declare a parameter with ‘decltype(auto)’
void f5(Octet decltype(auto)) {}
```

Compiled with `gcc-11 -std=c++20`. See: https://godbolt.org/z/xK769Pfjn

**Why do** `f4` **and** `f5` **not work?**

Comment: Hmmm is the language finally enforcing right const? 

Comment: `Octet auto` represents the type.  You can have right const or left const, but not "middle-const".

Comment: Why does `f5` not work? @DrewDormann

Comment: please add the complete compiler error message. I suppose this is gcc, because clangs error is different (although not much more helping)

Comment: All necessary messages are included. @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: @xmllmx `f5` is not valid C++ syntax.  It has no meaning.  You could perhaps look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737) to see the contexts where `decltype(auto)` has meaning in C++.  Or perhaps you could [edit] the question to describe what you think that parameter would mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As seen in [[dcl.spec.auto]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.spec.auto), when you use a placeholder here, the constraint needs to immediately precede the `auto`:

> placeholder-type-specifier:
> type-constraint_*opt* `auto`
> type-constraint_*opt* `decltype ( auto )`

This is simply a matter of syntax. The constraint isn't a general specifier like `const` is; it doesn't have a flexible position. Conceptually, you can think of `Octet auto` as one "word" representing the constrained type.

As for `f5`, this is not allowed as a parameter per p2:

> A placeholder-type-specifier of the form "type-constraint_*opt*
> `auto`" can be used as a decl-specifier of the decl-specifier-seq of a parameter-declaration of a function declaration...

No such text exists for `decltype(auto)`. In addition, per p6:

> A program that uses a placeholder type in a context not explicitly allowed in this subclause is ill-formed.

Logically, I'm not sure how I'd specify `decltype(auto)` to work in this context. Sure, it *could* be specified, but I don't think there's precedent in the language for it, so it would need to be motivated over an alternative that already has the desired effect.