# What to prefer: ‘operator auto’ or ‘operator decltype(auto)’ in modern C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++14, auto

This question was closed as a duplicate of [What are some uses of decltype(auto)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737/what-are-some-uses-of-decltypeauto), but actually there is no discussion in the referenced question at all about conversion operators, which are the primary topic of this question.

Starting from C++14 every class can have conversion methods `operator auto` and `operator decltype(auto)`, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    operator auto() { return 1; }
    operator decltype(auto) () { return 2.; }
};

int main()
{
   S s;
   std::cout << (int)s << '\n';
   std::cout << (double)s << '\n';
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ExhrGPGvv

If we have two options `operator auto` and `operator decltype(auto)`, is there any difference between them, and what option is better to choose on practice?

Comment: imho that should be `operator int() const { return 1; }`

Comment: usually `operator auto` is used for unknown type, e.g. if you are working with templates

Comment: there were some questions concerning this recently, not sure if this one was inspired by them. One revealed a very unnice inconsistency between compilers, so I would not use this just for the sake of AAA (though I am not a fan of AAA in general). Btw not trying to imply that this isnt a nice and interesting question. It is.

Comment: This is same as `decltype(auto) regularFunction()` and I've fund perfect duplicate.

Comment: +1 @AlbertoSinigaglia. Fedor, always use _real_ type names _(everywhere)_ when the type is known. It says what it does, and prevents from having to document the function _just_ for the return type... ;)