# python ctypes array data getting corrupted

Tags: python, c++, arrays, ctypes

I have the following files:

test.h:

```c
extern "C" {

void* createTest();
void getStrings(void* test_ptr, char*** strings, size_t* length);

}
```

test.cpp:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include "test.h"

class Test {
public:
    Test() {
        strings.push_back("test1");
        strings.push_back("test2");
        strings.push_back("test3");
        strings.push_back("test4");
    }
    std::vector<char *>& getStrings() {
        return strings;
    }

private:
    std::vector<char *> strings;
};

void* createTest() {
    return reinterpret_cast<void *>(new Test());
}

void getStrings(void* test_ptr, char*** strings, size_t* length) {
    auto inst = reinterpret_cast<Test *>(test_ptr);
    auto strs = inst->getStrings();
    *strings = strs.data();
    *length = strs.size();
}
```

test.py:

```py
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("test.so")

test_ptr = c_void_p()
test_ptr = lib.createTest()

strs_arr = POINTER(c_char_p)()
strs_len = c_size_t()

lib.getStrings(test_ptr, byref(strs_arr), byref(strs_len))

for i in range(0, strs_len.value):
    print("var {}: data={}".format(i, strs_arr[i]))
```

What I am trying to achieve is to retrieve the array of strings obtained from a c++ class member via python, however, it appears that the data ends up corrupted in some way as this is what I get upon executing the python file:

```
var 0: data=None
var 1: data=b'\x04'
var 2: data=b'test3'
var 3: data=b'test4'
```

I am using the following instructions to compile:

```
clang++-12 -fPIC -g -c test.cpp -o test.o
clang++-12 -fPIC -g -shared test.o -o test.so
```

Does anyone have any idea of what I could be doing wrong? I have tried changing the ctypes but I always get the same result. I have also tried debugging with gdb, and setting a breakpoint inside `getStrings(void* test_ptr, ...)` show the data is still intact by that point.

Comment: `new` already returns `void*` afaik. I changed the first two lines in `void getStrings` to have `Test*` and `std::vector<char*>` instead of `auto`, and it works, but I have no idea why

Comment: Changing to `std::vector<char *>` did not work for me, but changing to `std::vector<char *>&` did. I assume this means clang thinks auto is not a reference to the vector, even if the return type of `inst->getStrings()` is a reference? I'm confused, but my problem is solved, so thank you :D

Comment: Sorry bad typo I meant to write reference as well

Comment: @Lala5th Maybe post this as an answer? It seems to have fixed the problem for the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getStrings` the `auto` type deduction fails somehow. Changing it to:

```cpp
void getStrings(void* test_ptr, char*** strings, size_t* length) {
    auto inst = reinterpret_cast<Test *>(test_ptr);
    std::vector<char*>& strs = inst->getStrings();
    *strings = strs.data();
    *length = strs.size();
}
```

seems to fix the issue. I found that changing the `auto` to `auto&` for the second argument works fine as well.

Looking at it clearly now, it seems that `auto` is hesitant in detecting references, hence creating local variables, that inevitably go out of scope and cause UB.

[Relevant part of the standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type#auto.deduct-4). An other option is to use `decltype(auto)`.

[Relevant post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737/what-are-some-uses-of-decltypeauto)

Comment: It should be auto& strs = … otherwise strs is a copy (temporary object) and not the reference of the vector in inst… or your  explicit solution.