why use universal reference to accept function result rather than decltype(auto)?
auto && result = foo();

vs
decltype(auto) result = foo();

the only difference is that when the return type of foo is not reference, the type of former is rvalue reference but the type of latter is not reference.



declare
return int
return int&
return int&&




auto
int
int
int


auto&&
int&&
int&
int&&


decltype(auto)
int
int&
int&&




return int&& is considered a bad practice.

@MarekR True, but that has nothing to do with this question

Both are ok, but decltype(result) works more intuitively on the latter, so I'd prefer that.

"why?" Shorter to type ;-)

I (along with the Google powers-that-be) am generally against "almost always auto" https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Type_deduction, except in cases like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737/what-are-some-uses-of-decltypeauto but that is not really for local variable assignments, "Do not use decltype(auto) if a simpler option will work, because it's a fairly obscure feature, so it has a high cost in code clarity."

FWIW int && is not an "universal reference" but an rvalue reference.

@Artyer Oh right, I overlooked it

Consider:
constexpr auto f() -> /* #1 */  {
    /* #2 */ r = g();
    return r;
}

if g returns a prvalue (let's say int), then:



#1
#2
result




auto&&
auto&&
dangling reference


auto&&
decltype(auto)
dangling reference


decltype(auto)
auto&&
dangling reference


decltype(auto)
decltype(auto)
returns int




That just proves OP's point; 3rd row is UB, while 4th row is OK. decltype(auto) is more generic, and more faithfull to original.

So can we think that using decltype(auto) to accept the result of a function is a better choice than using auto &&

@nullptr • No.  We think that using auto&& (or any &&) as the return type of a function is always a terrible choice, with the exceptions of the implementation of std::move and std::forward.

@Eljay Using decltype(auto) at #1 and auto && at #2 still results in dangling reference

@nullptr • The decltype(auto) for #1 and auto&& for #2 results in && as the return type of the function.  Returning a && (explicitly or implicitly) is always a terrible choice.

@Eljay so, what is your point? This is not an argument against decltype(auto) being better

@nullptr • so, what is your point? Returning a && (explicitly or implicitly) is always a terrible choice.

@Eljay Using decltype(auto) to receive a function return value avoids the implicit return of an rvalue reference to a temporary variable in this case. If you do not think that using decltype(auto) is a better choice here, you should provide a rebuttal to this. arguments for a point rather than further proving it

@nullptr • Don't return a T&&.

@Eljay Certainly doesn't give me a lot of confidence in the core guidelines that their guideline for not returning T&& uses an example that returns T const&.

@Barry • A T const& is not a T&&.

@Eljay Yes, I know. That was literally the point of my comment. The guideline you linked to uses max as its example to not return T&&, but max doesn't return T&&.

@Barry • ahh, yes, I concur that the first example is out of place for F.45 and should be in its own guideline about paying attention to lifetime safety and care about having a dangling reference to a destructed temporary. (I blame the authors of the FAQ, it appears that Stroustrup & Sutter better brush up on their C++.)
