Using decltype(auto) for Return Type in Custom Callable Class Template
I'm experimenting with decltype(auto) in a custom callable class template that simplifies the behavior of std::function. My goal is to maintain the exact return type, including qualifiers like constness, reference etc, of the callable object when it is invoked. Here is the very simplified version of the class.
P.S. : C++ uses R instead of decltype(auto):
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()
I was wondering if I can use decltype(auto) with the same effect as R
template <typename>
class Callable;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Callable<R(Args...)>
{
public:
    template<typename F>
    Callable(F&& f) : func(std::forward<F>(f)) {}

    decltype(auto) operator()(Args... args) {
        return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::decay_t<R(Args...)> func;
};


Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109737/what-are-some-uses-of-decltypeauto.

In your code, your type Callable contains a pointer to function with return type R. The deduction decltype(auto) will yeild the same type as decltype(func(std::forward<Args>(args)...)), which is always R. Using R or decltype(auto) will yield the same type, but they are not 100% equivalent functionaly.
With decltype(auto), any instantiation of the function prototype will cause the body to also be instatiated to deduce the return type. Here's an example:
auto f = Callable<int()>{[]{ return 1; }};
using result_t = decltype(f()); // Causes the body of operator() to be instantiated!

This can impact using C++20 concepts since trying to detect the presence of a member function might instantiate template that could end up in a hard error!
Using R as return type will not instantiate the body until it is actually needed.

Wow! You're awesome! I actually checked what you said using cppinsights.io, and yes, using decltype(auto), that website shows that the body is instantiated! Very interesting! But I didn't quite understand the "This can impact using C++20 concepts since trying to detect the presence of a member function..." part. How come C++20 concepts can impact this? Would you please clarify a bit? I am not an experienced C++ developer, kind of junior. :) Thanks!

@Sam C++20 concepts is just a convenient way to do SFINAE. Basically, if you try to do SFINAE (the C++11 way or the concept way) on some Callable, you want to have some trait return a boolean, or prevent some templates from being instantiated, instead of getting a hard error. If f is changed to return void and you add a line R var; in your operator(), you'll observe that std::is_same_v<result_t, void> will be true if you use R (meaning it's SFINAE-friendly), while it would be a hard error if you use decltype(auto) (because void var; is ill-formed).
