# When would I want to use auto&& instead of decltype(auto) or ->decltype(return-expr) for the return type of a function definition?

Tags: c++, c++20, move-semantics, sfinae, perfect-forwarding

Take three functions returning prvalue, lvalue, xvalue:

```cpp
int   f();
int&  f(int);
int&& f(int, int);
```

and call them via a function returning `decltype(auto)`

```cpp
decltype(auto) returnsDecltypeOf(auto... x) {
    return f(x...);
}
```

This seems to work the way one would expect:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(returnsDecltypeOf()),    int>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(returnsDecltypeOf(1)),   int&>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(returnsDecltypeOf(1,1)), int&&>);
```

but if I change `decltype(auto)` to `auto&&`,

```cpp
auto&& returnsAutoRefRef(auto... x) {
    return f(x...);
}
```

things change:

```cpp
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(returnsAutoRefRef()),    int&&>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(returnsAutoRefRef(1)),   int&>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(returnsAutoRefRef(1,1)), int&&>);
```

I see the obvious difference that `returnsAutoRefRef` always returns a reference, so it can do the wrong thing, e.g. in the case of `f()`, where it will return a prvalue expression through an `auto&&` return value, which will be a dangling `int&&`.

Therefore it looks like `decltype(auto)` (or, if we plan to leverage SFINAE, even better `-> decltype(return-expr)`) is indeed the way to go to perfect forward the `return` expression back to the caller.

So my question is, when would I want to return `auto&&`? Why couldn't I just do `decltype(auto)`?

---

As far as I understand C++, a leading return type of `decltype(auto)` is the same thing as leading `auto` + trailing `-> decltype(return expression)`, ***besides the fact that the latter is SFINAE-friendly and the former is not***. Now, I'm not sure how much this SFINAE-specific thing influences the answer to the question!

Comment: `auto&&` will apply the same deduction rules as with template deduction with `T&&`. You will of course always end up with a reference type that way.

Comment: I would say that `auto&&` is never right to use as a return type.  It locks you in to returning by reference and returning an rvalue reference has limited use cases.

Comment: Here's a [textbook example](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100290) of the difference, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67282639/c20-viewsjoin-goes-into-an-infinite-loop-on-generated-nested-rangessingle.

Comment: Related: [decltype(auto) vs auto&& to perform generic handling of function's return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089682/decltypeauto-vs-auto-to-perform-generic-handling-of-functions-return-type)

Answer (score 4):

There are exactly two cases where `decltype(auto)` is different from `auto&&`.

As you've noted, when you return a prvalue, `decltype(auto)` returns by value, and `auto&&` returns a dangling rvalue reference (probably undesireable).

The second case is when you return an entity directly. E.g.:

```cpp
struct X {
    int i;
    decltype(auto) return_entity() { return i; }
    decltype(auto) return_expression() { return (i); }
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(X{}.return_entity()), int>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(X{}.return_expression()), int&>);
```

(Because `decltype(i)` is `int`, but `decltype((i))` is `int&`).

---

In *every* other scenario they are the same. You may want to use `auto&&` to emphasise you are returning a reference, or `decltype(auto)` to emphasise you are perfect forwarding something.

As an example, this documentation for [`std::forward_like`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward_like) is shown as returning `auto&&` because it always returns a reference.

But if you could possibly return a prvalue, `decltype(auto)` is obviously preferable.